# why tempdb is throwing an error but still database having around of 5gb space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tempdb

[image]

when we are working on the application, suddenly we got the error as pasted in above screen shot, we cannot able to perform any thing, but if i look into the database still the having 5 gb more space available, what could be the reason? kindly advice

Comment: This question belongs in 'Server Fault' or 'Database Administrators'.  Does TEMPDB have 5 gb of free space, or is the free space in your production database?  How much space is free on the actual HDD?

Comment: did you look at the space in TEMP db and make sure tempdb isn't set to have restricted growth?

Comment: 500 gb HDD space is there, my primary log is 1 MB with unrestricted growth, log is 10 percent with unrestricted, of the database is suggest able once, please advice

Answer (score 0):

Did you perform a massively IO intensive action that hammered TempDB. This could include an index rebuild of a very large index with Sort in TempDB = ON. Where everything in TempDB is as the name suggests temporary, just because you have 5gb free now does not mean you had 5gb free when error occurred.

If the problem is ongoing then I would suggest you have corruption in TempDB and you should restart the instance. This will drop TempDB and re-create it, curing the corruption